# How to make today extension disable？

Tags: ios, today-extension

My app want to release,but my today extension didn't finish,so I want to make today widget disable and I want to recover it later then continue to develop it,who knows it?Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I try to delete the extension target but don't know how to recover.I also continue to develop it later,just make it disable temporally.

Comment: We are a team,others maybe push a new commit.So this way like to cause some problems.I already solve my problem.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to desable this extension, do the following steps

1. Go to your project Settings
2. Select the target that you want to disable the extension
3. Go to Build Phases tab
4. Open Target Dependencies
5. Remove the extension (just the one that you don't whant)

also after this do:

If you want to keep the sourcecode and only remove the today widget:

1. Go to your project Settings
2. Select the target that you want to disable the extension
3. Select General -> Embedded binaries
4. remove the TodayWidgetName.appex file with the minus button

after all this do a clean (`cmd + shift + k`)

Comment: The first way is like to no useful,The second way is work for me.Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome.. if my answer helped you, pls accept it and give me an upvote :)  tkks

Comment: I'm very sorry.My reputation less then 15.I can't vote.

Comment: If you accep my answer you will get 2 points, and goes to 16, just click at check Mark to accept it